# HP dv6-2150ca don't boot after RAM upgrade

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory

I've HP dv6-2150ca with Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.
I had 4 gb RAM. 
I upgrade to 8 gb RAM. Both from same manufacturer and purchased at same time.
Specs of RAM
[Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=2836F433A5CA7304)

When I start laplop it says "due to recent change in hardware or software, windows can't start......"
And offer 2 options 1. Launch repair utility (recomended)   2. start windows normally

I tried both options, but it came to same screen after some time.
I tried with single chip from the set, but it shows blue screen with error messages

One last thing, on the laptop RAM slots 1.5 V is written. I'm not sure if it is important here.

I installed old memory, everything is perfect.

Please advice.

Comment: The RAM is the wrong voltage. Apparently the `ca` and `us` versions of the laptop are different.

Comment: I called HP before I bought it. They say `ca`, `us` is just to keep track of the country. Rest is same. Even on Crucial website, it shows the same RAM, even if I choose the CANADA as country there is no `ca`. Take a look http://www.crucial.com/store/listmodel.aspx?pl=Pavilion%20DV6%20Series&mfgr=HP%20-%20Compaq&cat=

Comment: RAM can run in dual voltage, and the board on the laptop should be able to accept this.

Comment: @gmailuser When you complete booting into Windows, does it say you have 8gb? Also, when you tried single sticks, did you try both individually or just one?

Comment: @Pretzel when I go in bios it shows 8gb.

Comment: @gmailuser I mean when you finish booting into windows, right click "computer" >> Properties...how much RAM does it say you have?

Comment: @Pretzel As I said in the question, it doesn't boot at all with new RAM

Comment: @gmailuser Ah, my mistake, overlooked that. Since your BIOS recognizes the RAM, did you run a check on the memory?

Comment: @Pretzel There is HP tool to check the memory, but it says, it will take 9 hrs to check the memory.

Comment: @gmailuser Sounds like bad memory, that or the voltage is actually off as suggested by Nathan. What is printed on the original memory? If the voltages are the same it sounds like you just got a bad batch. Has to be either not compatible or just a bad memory and needs to be swapped.

Comment: @Pretzel  No voltage is printed on old memory. But, on the laptop slots it says 1.5 V

Comment: @gmailuser This memory sounds bad or there really is a voltage missmatch.

Comment: @gmailuser I would revert back to your old memory, and either request the swap the memory with another set (it is very possible the memory is just bad) and see if another set of matching sticks solves your problem, or return what you've purchased and buy memory that matches all of your requirements as well as voltage (if possible).

Comment: When you make RAM changes, you shouldn't even try to boot into Windows until you thoroughly test the RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the long string of comments, it sounds very much like you have gotten bad memory or you have a voltage miss-match (and this memory is not compatible with dual voltage). I would recommend that you re-install your old memory and return this set to be swapped with another new set (it is very possible the memory is just bad) to see if another set of matching sticks solves your problem, or return what you've purchased and buy memory that matches all of your requirements as well as voltage (if possible).

Comment: **JUST FYI** I just hung up the call with the HP tech support. **What they say is the if the slots in laptop are 1.5 V, it'll support upto 1.5 V. So, if we use 1.35 V RAM, it is fine, but if we use 1.8 V, machine can't support that.**

Comment: @Pretsel Looks like memory issue. I'll try tonight to run with one chip at a time with new memory.

Comment: @gmailuser update on any changes

Comment: @Pretsel Single chip at a time didn't work. Also, I updated the bios. Same result. I installed the `CPU-z` and max frequency it shows on `SPD` tab is < 700 and the frequency in bios is above 10000. I'm not sure if they are related.

Comment: @gmailuser sounds like bad modules

Comment: @Pretse I think last resource is to return it. But thanks for your valuable time and interest.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you push it the RAMs until they have clicked in. This may require some force. I know this from experience that when people get new RAM they tend to be gentle with it. For it to work properly you need to make sure it is in all the way. After you plug in the new RAM, try to use "Last Known Good Configuration" by going into Advanced Boot Option (Do this by pressing F8 at startup). Let me know what happens.

Comment: What am I suppose to change in the advanced boot option?

Comment: Choose the "Last Known Good Configuration" option

Comment: Last known good will only load his last known good copy of the registry, it doesn't solve a RAM issue.

Comment: Maybe it is not a RAM issue. If it was a RAM issue the computer would give beep codes instead of booting up and showing all the BIOS and such.

Comment: Also gmail user, go ahead and go into your BIOS setup and check how much it is displaying for the installed Memory (RAM).

Comment: @Tech1337 it shows 8gb in the bios.

Comment: @Tech1337 No, it would not beep because as he stated it is recognized in his BIOS. Bad or memory that is not compatible does not always cause a board to beep.

Comment: @gmailuser Can you specify the specs for the old RAM? as in the speed and such

Comment: @Tech1337 I don't have all the details as it came with manufacturer.

Comment: If you read the white label on the RAM itself, it has some of the details I need. Could you write down verbatim what you see on the RAM?

Comment: As you stated that one of the RAM inserted alone gave you a blue screen, what was the error code on the blue screen. Also could you try plugging in the second RAM alone? Same results? After that try inserting both of the RAM and run diagnostics on the memory if your BIOS allows you to. It could be that one of the RAM went bad.

Comment: @Tech1337 This has all already been gone over and stated. Please read all comments and original post.

Comment: @Pretzel Oh sorry about that. I did not see those comments. Pretty new to this website. Created my account yesterday, haha. 
As pretezel said, the RAM maybe has gone bad through ESD. Voltage shouldn't really matter since lower voltage is typically better for your CPU.

Comment: @Tech1337 Lower voltage is better, but sometimes boards cannot run dual-voltage (but I would think this much less likely). And welcome to the community!